# <a> tag inside Tree View not working

Tags: asp.net, treeview, anchor

I created a Tree View out of a file system in ASP.NET.  When the user clicks on a file tree node I want the file to either open (if the browser can open it) or download.  In my code the files are actually written as anchor tags:

```
for (int ctr = 0, cnt = filesInDirectory.Length; ctr < cnt; ctr++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(filesInDirectory[ctr].Name, filesInDirectory[ctr].FullName);
            newNode.Text = "<a href=" + StringToURL(filesInDirectory[ctr].FullName) + ">" + filesInDirectory[ctr].Name + "</a>";

            baseNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }
```

This work in creating the anchor tags, but when I click on a tag nothing happens.  If I right-click and save the link, then paste it into the URL it works fine.  How do I enable left clicking?

**FIXED:**
Your code worked after I added "http:" to the front of the file path.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [NavigateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.navigateurl.aspx) property of the TreeNode to provide the target link.

```
newNode.Text = filesInDirectory[ctr].Name;
newNode.NavigateUrl = StringToURL(filesInDirectory[ctr].FullName);
```